# Issue with permissions to access specific file types on Android 13

Tags: android, angular, ionic5

I am facing a specific issue with permissions in my Android app, which is targeted for Android 13 and compatible with earlier versions such as Android 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, etc. Currently, I am using the following permissions for images, videos, and audio in the manifest:

```html
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion"/>
     <uses-permission
         android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
         android:maxSdkVersion="32" />
```

The peculiarity is that these permissions are working as expected on versions earlier than Android 13, but on Android 13, I can't access specific file types, such as PDFs and stickers, which can also be saved in storage.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue on Android 13, or do you have insights into additional permissions needed for this scenario? Is there something specific in Android 13 that I should consider when dealing with permissions for accessing different file types?

```js
this.diagnostic.requestExternalStorageAuthorization()
```

I always get a response of DENIED_ALWAYS. This behavior is consistent across various devices running Android 13.

I appreciate any help or guidance in advance!

Comment: Those pdf files are not created by your app i suppose.

Comment: A pdf file is no image or video or audio so no permission to read or list.

Comment: The files are not generated by my app. How do major apps like WhatsApp manage to access any type of file?

Comment: MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

Comment: I don't know if it's correct, but I'm using this method to check the permission this.androidPermissions.checkPermission(
'android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES'
) and if you don't have permission, await this.androidPermissions.requestPermission(
'android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES'
)

Comment: Repeat: `A pdf file is no image `. A read media images permission does not help for not media files like pdf.